# Double-sided printing is grayed out? UBUNTU 16.04 / BROTHER MFC-7360n printer/scanner

Tags: printing

I use Ubuntu 16.04 and have recently installed a Brother MFC-7360n printer/scanner/fax. Whenever I attempt to print double-sided I get a grayed out option for double sided (see image attached). I challenge ANYONE to figure that one out :>

[image: Print dialog for Brother MFC07306n]

Comment: my actual printer is a **MFC-7360n** (not the model listed above)

Comment: My brother printer works fine for double sided printing but I downloaded the correct driver off their website.

Answer (score 4):

The driver for the Brother MFC-7360n has no double-side printing feature hence the "not available".

The online [brochure](http://www.brother-usa.com/VirData/Content/en-US/MFC/ModelBrochures/MFC%207000%20Series%20Brochure%2004%2030%2011.pdf) for this model says:

```
Duplex Printing
– Helps save paper 
(Not available on MFC-7360n)
```

Comment: we made some small edits; hope you do not mind :D

Comment: @Rinzwind Not at all. My pleasure. Thanks and sorry for the late answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was figuring this for my new Epson L361 MFD as the duplex/two sided option was missing. Then realised I can use the option to print odd(or even, as the case may be) numbered pages first, then put the printed sheets into the input tray to print the even numbered pages next. Tried it out, and it worked (obviously). Even if the duplex option was available, it would do the same thing, except decide on which to print first - even or odd numbered pages.